# How do we ensure that bug fixes on maintenance branch are merged back to trunk?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, continuous-integration

We operate Trunk Based Development.  Our latest and greatest code is continuously integrated into our trunk, until we are ready to get it UAT'd.  At that stage we create a release candidate branch from the trunk for UAT, and new development continues in the trunk.  Once this release candidate has passed UAT it will be tagged and released to Live, and a maintenance branch created from the tag which will live until the next major (UAT'd) release.

The question is, how to handle the merging of bug fixes.  If a bug is fixed on the Maintenance Branch during UAT, this code fix should be merged to the trunk and to the release candidate.  If a UAT bug is fixed during UAT, this code fix should be merged to trunk.

We all know this, but sometimes merges get missed, and we've had cases where bugs that were fixed in Live have re-surfaced again as the fixes weren't applied to all the required branches (trunk and release candidate).

We have started referencing the commits to other branches now in our commit comments (essentially our own poor mans merge info) in order to track this.

However **is there any way for us to be absolutely sure that all commits to the maintenance branch get merged to trunk and release candidate, and that all commits to the release candidate get merged to trunk?**

Comment: If you have a fairly standard development cycle then you should schedule merges between them. Usually every two weeks or so seems to be the sweet spot for my team.

Comment: As outlined above, our process is to merge the individual commits back to trunk (and release candidate), rather than do a full merge of the branch -> giving each developer responsibility for their own fixes. However, maybe freezing the maintenance branch and doing a full branch merge back to trunk and release candidate the day before release is a good way to catch anything that was missed.  I'm guessing subversion would be smart enough to only merge across what had been forgotten about (assuming good merge info).

Comment: Correct. I'd add a buffer of at least another day (so you would merge _two_ days before release) which would give you enough time to manage strange (but entirely explainable) merge changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no way for the VCS to spot the difference between bug fix and ongoing development the short answer is there is no way to be 100% sure,  a good tracking system that has a check list for the developers may help but even threatening to fire or **shoot** offenders does not ensure it doesn't happen.  *Actually doing so cuts down the repeat offenders though!*

Comment: Well, every commit on the maintenance branch and release candidate would have to be merged to trunk, so we don't really have to differentiate between the commits. Communication was sent out before, and we have clarified this and sent it out again (backed up with wiki pages), but yet we still encountered the problem -> some people just forget.

Answer (score 0):

For permanent jobs

- merge all commits of the maintenance branch to trunk and release candidate
- merge all commits of the release candidate to trunk

You can use (obviously!!!) special post-commit hook(s)

**Prerequisites**

- Working Copies (on SVN-server host) for trunk + RC branch

*Additionally, not mandatory (see below)*

- Pre-commit hook, which can block|pass commit from custom userlist without changing hook's code

**Business-logic (TBT!!!)**

- If commit affects any of monitored branches (use `svnlook dirs-changed` for this task): merge to (known) targets is needed. You can have list of targets for future mandatory merge(s) at this point
- Try to merge

  - `svn up` WC(s) of target(s)
  - Try to merge: `svn merge <options> --dry-run`
  - If no conflicts on test-merge - perform merge in WC and commit mergeset, return exit-code "OK" and finish hook
  - If conflicts on merge was found and, thus, human intervention in merge is a must, you can select any path:

    - Inform committer about problem and about his next awaited operation (merge with resolving conflicts)
    - Inform committer about problem and about his next awaited operation and somehow drop username of commiter into banlist for pre-commit hook (prohibit future commits except hand-made mergesets into targets)
- If commit is mergeset into TARGET(s) from blocked user - remove user from ban